# My environment variables are not recognized in Azure - ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: azure, deployment, asp.net-core-mvc, environment-variables, azure-web-app-service

I have a project in ASP.NET Core with a database, I published it through GitHub Actions and created a Web Service App. I configured my environment variable with the `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` method.

I created my environment variable on my machine and added it to Azure under "Environment variables". When I run it on my machine, the variable is recognized and connects normally to the database, but in Azure it says that it is not defined, even though I have already saved it. Does anyone know what the reason for this might be?

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
        var provider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
        var configuration = provider.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

        var connString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(connString))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("A variável de ambiente DATABASE_CONNECTION_STRING não está definida.");
        }
    }
}
```

`Appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I've looked for information and haven't found anything that helps me.

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean when you say, "...added it to Azure under 'Environment variables'."?

Comment: @luis which server you are using, MSSQL or MySql.

Comment: @luis - You need to add the Variables as secrets with same name  in GitHub.

Comment: Have you added it under appsetings or connection string?